# How do I get rid of the '$' in the destination folder so I can download Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

Im trying to download Anaconda on Windows 10 but [there is an error in the destination folder due to a '$'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYUH4.png) . I changed the username on my PC but it still doesn't change on the destination folder. How can I change the '$'?

Comment: please paste the error message as text rather than picture, it might help future users who encountered same error

Answer (score 0):

You are probably copying the path to your destination folder from linux command terminal. And while copying you are probably selecting the $ sign. I am not sure if you know or not, but that $ sign is not supposed to be copied. Delete it from the destination path if you have copied it. Or just dont copy the $.
If this still doesnt resolve your issue, show the complete path that you are trying to enter as the destination path.

Comment: Im not copying it from anywhere. It automatically selects this destination path, and when I manually remove the '$', it says that the path is not writeable

Comment: Can you share the prompt with complete path written, without the error prompt